# Google Apps Script - how to view HEAD Deployment ID / link?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am not sure if this changed recently with the new IDE, but I thought that the deployment ID / URL of one's web app didn't change when one created additional versions. However, at this moment I am confused.

In my process.env, I have a link to my GAS URL which performs a `doGet(e)`. However, when I go to manage deployments in my GAS file, I cannot find the corresponding deployment ID / link anywhere (not under Active nor Archived), yet, the code is working and reflects the latest changes in my script, so I believe it's the head deployment. Is this correct, or am I using some legacy deployment ID or something that's hidden?

Or perhaps asked differently, if I have the `/macros/s/{deployment_id}/exec` URL, is there a way within my Google account to find the corresponding script file and version / deployment?

Lastly, if the documentation recommends using versioned deployments, does this mean we have to update the GAS URL each time (e.g., if it's a public facing web app)?

**Edit: others have encountered this: https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/qhiqjGabQpI/m/q5i31yydCAAJ**

Answer (score 2):

To view the all deployment IDs, including HEAD (aka version 0):

1. Switch to Legacy Editor
2. Go to `Publish` => `Deploy From Manifest`
3. You'll get a list of deployment, with ID next to each one
4. Copy the ID of `Version 0`
5. Paste the ID in the corresponding Google Cloud Console => Configuration
6. Switch again to New Editor :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: The HEAD deployment link/ID can also be found in the new editor: click the new editor's 'Deploy' drop-down button, choose 'Test deployments'. The dialog that opens up will have the URL in the right panel. If it's not there, and you're configuring the app as a web app, you may have to select 'web app' from the 'Select type' panel on the left side of the dialog. Or 'web app' may already be selected if you've previously published a versioned deployment, and in that case the URL will be already be there

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp) with Apps Script for the development simply you can use clasp commands agents the given App Script Project.

- `clasp deployments` to see the list of deployments including HEAD

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*There ways of viewing and editing deployments is set out in [this article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments), which I will go through below. If you can not view the desired deployment using these methods, then I would urge you to [contact Google Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en).*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation on creating and managing deployments:

> There are two types of deployments:
>
> - Head deployments, which are always synced to the current project code.
> - Versioned deployments, which are connected to a specific project version.

---

> #### View versioned deployments
>
> New editor:
>
> To view the deployments of an Apps Script project, at the top, click **Deploy > Manage deployments**.

---

> #### Find a deployment ID
>
> New editor:
>
> 1. Open the Apps Script project.
> 2. At the top right, click Deploy > Manage deployments.
>
> The deployment ID appears on the current deployment.

---

#### References:

- [Create and manage deployments | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments)

Answer (score 0):

[This document](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43#important-point) maybe can help you.

Follow step 5 and step 6 in the IMPORTANT POINT.

```
5. Update the deployment as follows:
  a. Open "New deployment" dialog with "Deploy" -> "Manage deployments".
  b. For the 1st deployment, click the pencil icon for editing the deployment.
  c. Set "version" as "New version".
  d. When you want to change the description, please modify it.
  e.Click "Deploy" button.
6.Testing
  Please use above sample curl command. By this, you can confirm that sample2 is returned without changing the endpoint.
```

Answer (score 0):

Go in to "Overview" of your editor, click on the "HEAD" tab, then the URL will change to the format of:

https://script.google.com/home/projects/<project_id>/deployments/<deployment_id>

Boom! So your Project URL becomes:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/<deployment_id>/exec